# Jquery - Accordion

Tags: jquery

How to make an accordion in jquery to select none of the menu while loading

Comment: Check [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/?p=1.1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

> Selector for the active element. Set
>   to false to display none at start.
>   Needs collapsible: true.

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: false });
```

or Get or set the active option, after **init**

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", false );
```